# How to specify as parameter a generic type such as List/Map<T>?

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic method defined in this way:

```
public <T> T processGeneric(..., Class<T> type){
       //do something
}
```

I want this method to be as generic as possible, so any type should be accepted.

It generally works as long the passed type is an object, but what about a generic type itself? 
For example:

```
HashMap<String, String> result;
processGeneric(..., HashMap<String, String>.class); //this does not work
```

The only way I have to make everything work is to declare result as raw type:

```
HashMap result;
result = processGeneric(..., HashMap.class); //this works but gives me a warning
```

But...is this really the only way?

I'm using Java-7.

Comment: What is your java version?

Comment: The line you have marked with _"//this one says that return type is incorrect"_ should work (with warning). If it gives an error, it's because of some other parameters.

Comment: No, I have to change the result type to a raw type like in the second example to get the warning... my java version is 1.7

Comment: Upsie sorry! You're right! edited

Comment: Please specify more details what's going on inside this method. Are you using `type.newInstance()` inside your `processGeneric` method? What else do you do with this created instance?

Answer (score 2):

You can (and you should) avoid using raw types this way:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> result;
result = processGeneric(HashMap.class);
```

However you cannot avoid unchecked cast (at least without knowing the details of the `processGeneric` method body). The only alternative is to create your own type which explicitly binds the `HashMap` type parameters:

```
public class StringIntegerMap extends HashMap<String, Integer> {}

HashMap<String, Integer> result;
result = processGeneric(StringIntegerMap.class);
```

This might be acceptable if you have not so many different generic parameters.

In general remember that "raw type" warning is evil and must be avoided as much as possible. "Unchecked cast" warning sometimes is necessary evil and it's ok if you know what are you doing.

Answer (score 1):

jackson has good example for such cases:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> yourMap = new ObjectMapper().readValue(..., new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Integer>>() {});
```

that is based on the idea of [super type tokens](http://gafter.blogspot.com.by/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html):

Code from the article:

```
public abstract class TypeReference<T> {

    private final Type type;
    private volatile Constructor<?> constructor;

    protected TypeReference() {
        Type superclass = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        if (superclass instanceof Class) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Missing type parameter.");
        }
        this.type = ((ParameterizedType) superclass).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    /**
     * Instantiates a new instance of {@code T} using the default, no-arg
     * constructor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T newInstance()
            throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException,
                   InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {
        if (constructor == null) {
            Class<?> rawType = type instanceof Class<?>
                ? (Class<?>) type
                : (Class<?>) ((ParameterizedType) type).getRawType();
            constructor = rawType.getConstructor();
        }
        return (T) constructor.newInstance();
    }

    /**
     * Gets the referenced type.
     */
    public Type getType() {
        return this.type;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<String> l1 = new TypeReference<ArrayList<String>>() {}.newInstance();
        List l2 = new TypeReference<ArrayList>() {}.newInstance();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

param type is an Class object:

1, `Class clazz = XXX.class;`

2, `Class clazz = Class.forName("xxx.xxx.xxx");`

And there no `HashMap<String, String>.class`,or you can defined new class extends it,then can use 'newClassName.class' instead it.